# Custom block for display of scorm interactions with tree button

Tags: moodle

I can't insert the values of the third interaction of a scorm . I see the values of the second interaction reported. Where am I wrong? thank you

```
this is the code
SELECT scc.userid AS User, sct.name AS Name, scc.scoid AS SCORM_ID, sct.module AS Module, scc.value AS Touch_1, sct.value AS touch_2, sct.value AS Touch_3
FROM

(SELECT u.id AS userid, st.scoid AS scoid, st.value AS value

FROM prefix_course AS c

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm AS sc ON sc.course=c.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm_scoes_track AS st ON st.scormid=sc.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id=st.userid

WHERE st.element='cmi.interactions_0.time') AS scc

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT c.fullname Course, sc.name AS module, st.scoid AS scoid, u.id AS userid, u.firstname name, st.attempt as Attempt, st.value AS value

FROM prefix_course AS c

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm AS sc ON sc.course=c.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm_scoes_track AS st ON st.scormid=sc.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id=st.userid

WHERE st.element='cmi.interactions_1.time') AS sct 





ON sct.scoid=scc.scoid

AND sct.userid=scc.userid

ORDER BY scc.userid
```

this is the wrong result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got a 3rd element in the SQL :)

Rather than using sub queries, I would probably use a `GROUP BY` if you want to put the values in columns.

```
SELECT u.id AS userid, u.firstname,
    c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename,
    s.id AS scormid, s.name AS scormname,
    MAX(CASE WHEN sst.element = 'cmi.interactions_0.time' THEN sst.value ELSE '' END) AS time0,
    MAX(CASE WHEN sst.element = 'cmi.interactions_1.time' THEN sst.value ELSE '' END) AS time1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN sst.element = 'cmi.interactions_2.time' THEN sst.value ELSE '' END) AS time2
FROM mdl_course c
JOIN mdl_scorm s ON s.course = c.id
JOIN mdl_scorm_scoes_track sst ON sst.scormid = s.id
    AND sst.element IN ('cmi.interactions_0.time', 'cmi.interactions_1.time', 'cmi.interactions_2.time')
JOIN mdl_user u ON u.id = sst.userid
GROUP BY u.id, u.firstname, c.id, c.fullname, s.id, s.name
```

Comment: great Russell! thank you with all my heart